# Why do enemies always target my archers?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-online

When engaging in a battle with melee enemies, they always make a complete charge to damage my archers. They will forgo any defense and just charge right at them.

Why do enemies favour this strategy? As archers are not that strong, I assume they are an easy target.

So what tactics can I use to protect them, other than backing them into a tile and surrounding them with melee soldiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answer based on earlier iterations of the game; I consider it valid because it was applicable to pretty much all of them)

Because ranged units can't fire when there's at least one enemy in melee range.

It's not just that they're a soft target, it's that engaging them in melee strips them (and by inference, you) of their best way of inflicting damage. You may have noticed that they do much less damage in melee than at range.

(Incidentally, this is not unique to HoMM, as it's sound strategy in general  -- in the rock-paper-scissors of Ye Olde Tyme ground warfare, this is why cavalry trumps archers)

Countertactics: 
Essentially, make sure the enemy has very limited options to put his forces adjacent to your archers:

1. Put your own melee units out in front of your archers where the enemy has to get through the former to get to the latter.
2. Use what terrain the game provides as cover
3. Any debuffs that slow the faster enemies down will come in handy.